# JavaScript: How to group two-dimensional array based matching fields on two input arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have the following arrays `a` and `b` as shown：

```js
var a = [
  {id: 1, name: "phone"},
  {id: 2,  name: "nick"}
];

var b = [
  {id: 7, parentId: 1, name: "phone_item1"},
  {id: 8, parentId: 2, name: "phone_item2"},
  {id: 9, parentId: 1, name: "nick_item1"},
  {id: 10, parentId: 2, name: "nick_item2"}
];

//You want to filter by A array id
const filterIds = a.map(({ id }) => id);

//My attempt
const c = Object.values(b.reduce((r, c) => {
  r[c.parentId] = r[c.parentId] || [];
  r[c.parentId].push(c);
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(c)
```

I am trying to obtain the following two-dimensional array:

```
[[
  {id: 7, parentId: 1, name: "phone_item1"},
  {id: 9, parentId: 1, name: "nick_item1"}
],[
  {id: 8, parentId: 2, name: "phone_item2"},
  {id: 10, parentId: 2, name: "nick_item2"}
]]
```

The resulting array should be according to the comparison between the `id` of array `a` and `parentId` of array `b`, so that this style of 2D array results. For some reason my attempt is not working - can you help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `a` and `filterIds`? They aren't used anywhere

Comment: The code seems to work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not suring if I'm missing something here - assuming I understand your question correctly, a simple implementation would be to map each item of `a` such that the mapping returns a filtered subset of `b` on matches between `bItem.parentId === aItem.id` (where `aItem` and `bItem` are items of respective lists being iterated):

```js
var a = [
  {id: 1, name: "phone"},
  {id: 2,  name: "nick"}
];

var b = [
  {id: 7, parentId: 1, name: "phone_item1"},
  {id: 8, parentId: 2, name: "phone_item2"},
  {id: 9, parentId: 1, name: "nick_item1"},
  {id: 10, parentId: 2, name: "nick_item2"}
];

/* Map each item in a to a classification of b against a */
const result = a.map(aItem => {

  /* For current aItem, return a subset of b, filtered by matches 
  on bItem.parentId === aItem.id (ie the classification criteria) */
  return b.filter(bItem => bItem.parentId === aItem.id)
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Type error `c.paentId` and relation for `filterIds` which was missing:

```js
var a = [
  {id: 1, name: "phone"},
  {id: 2,  name: "nick"}
];

var b = [
  {id: 7, parentId: 1, name: "phone_item1"},
  {id: 8, parentId: 2, name: "phone_item2"},
  {id: 9, parentId: 1, name: "nick_item1"},
  {id: 10, parentId: 2, name: "nick_item2"}
];

const filterIds = a.map(({ id }) => id);

//The problem code
const c = Object.values(b.reduce((r, c) => {
      r[c.parentId] = filterIds.includes(c.parentId) && r[c.parentId] || [];
      r[c.parentId].push(c);
      return r;
    }, {}));


console.log(c);
```